# tRPC How to encapsulate middleware?

Tags: typescript, trpc.io

I am trying to put middleware into its own function but I am struggling to get proper typescript typing on it.

At the moment I am typing the middleware as follows, but this isn't ideal because the type information of context and metadata are lost after returning from the middleware.

Inside the middleware

```js
import { MiddlewareFunction } from "@trpc/server/dist/declarations/src/internals/middlewares";
import { TRPCError } from "@trpc/server";


export const authMiddleware : MiddlewareFunction<any, any, any> = async ({ ctx, next, path, rawInput, type, meta }) => {
  if (!meta?.auth)
    return next();

  // some random logic

  return next();
}
```

And this is how I want to consume it

```js
createRouter()
  .middleware(authMiddleware)
  .mutation('', {
    meta: {
      auth: "user",
      appCheck: true
    },
    input: object({
      workshopId: idSchema,
    }),
    resolve: async ({ input, ctx, type }) => {
    // Here ctx has been widened to any
    // ...
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
const t = initTRPC.context<Context>().create();
const middleware = t.middleware;

const authMiddleware = t.middleware(({ next, ctx }) => {
  if (!ctx.session) {
    throw new TRPCError({
      code: "UNAUTHORIZED",
    });
  }
  return next({
    ctx: {
      // Infers the `session` as non-nullable
      session: ctx.session,
    },
  });
})
```

Comment: In case anyone’s confused by the simplicity of the answer: This is how it works now as of tRPC v10. 

Comment: How does this make the middleware shareable?
I'm trying to write a middleware that can be use across a monorepo and would like it to live as it's own function somewhere in the project, not necessarily having to call `initTRPC.context<Context>().create();`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (trpc v9.27), so I took the type directly from the middleware method on the trpc router.

```js
import * as trpc from "@trpc/server"

// context for router
const createContext = async () => ({hi: "hi"})

type Context = trpc.inferAsyncReturnType<typeof createContext>

// router initialization function
const trpcRouter = () => trpc.router<Context>()

const router = trpcRouter()
// don't forget to add the return type for your middleware
// in the generic
const init = router.middleware<Context>
type MiddlewareFunction = Parameters<typeof init>[0]

// now use for your middlewares
const myMiddleware: MiddlewareFunction = ({next, ctx}) => {
    console.log("my context", ctx)
    next()
}

// go nuts and use it where you want
export const myCoolRoutes = router
    .middleware(myMiddleware)
    .query("coolio", ({ctx}) => true)
```

Do note that if you plan on mutating the context inside one of your middleware functions the `router.middleware` generic should reflect that. For example, if you want to add keys to your context in a middleware you'd define a new context type that adds your desired keys:

```js
// add your keys to context
type keys = {newKey: number}
const mutatingMiddleware = router.middleware<Context & keys>
type Mutate = Parameters<typeof mutatingMiddleware>[0]

const mutatator: Mutate = ({ctx, next}) => {
    return next({ctx: {...ctx, newKey: 0}})
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it

```
import { MiddlewareFunction, ProcedureParams } from '@trpc/server'


export type BaseMiddlewareFunction<$ContextIn> = MiddlewareFunction<
  { _ctx_out: $ContextIn } & ProcedureParams,
  ProcedureParams
>



export const myMiddleWareFunc: BaseMiddlewareFunction<
  {
    req?: Request
  }
> = (opts) => {
  const req =  opts.ctx.req 

  return opts.next({ctx: {
    ...opts.ctx, 
    'foo': 'bar'
  }})
}
```